# Android parse Json with chinese characters

Tags: android, json

I got a valid Json string(at least every onlinevalidator I tried says so) which contains some chinese characters.

The json string is the following:

{"title":"\u8981\u805e--\u83ef\u723e\u8857\u65e5\u5831","url":"http://cn.wsj.com","desc":"\u300a\u83ef\u723e\u8857\u65e5\u5831\u300b\u4e2d\u6587\u7db2\u7d61\u7248\u6700\u65b0\u8ca1\u7d93\u8981\u805e","imageUrl":null,"lastUpdate":"1327588937","items":[{"title":"\u4e16\u8cbf\u7d44\u7e54\u7e3d\u5e79\u4e8b\ufe55\u4eba\u6c11\u5e63\u5e63\u503c\u88ab\u4f4e\u4f30\ufe50\u4f46\u4f4e\u4f30\u7a0b\u5ea6\u4e0d\u660e","desc":"\u4e16\u754c\u8cbf\u6613\u7d44\u7e54\u7e3d\u5e79\u4e8b\u5e15\u65af\u5361\u723e\uff0e\u62c9\u7c73\u9031\u56db\u8868\u793a\ufe50\u4eba\u6c11\u5e63\u532f\u7387\u88ab\u660e\u986f\u4f4e\u4f30\ufe50\u4f46\u4f4e\u4f30\u7a0b\u5ea6\u9084\u4e0d\u6e05\u695a\u3002","url":"http://cn.wsj.com/big5/20120126/BCHc-20120126WR182711424.asp?source=rss","pubdate":null}]}

Now when i Parse the JsonString in Android via new JsonObject(jsonString) I only got some squares instead of characters.

Why cant android handle this json string?

Any help would be apreciated.

If anyone would like to have the server Ressource, it can be found under:

// edit
url removed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static String test(){
    String testResult= "";
    try {
        HttpGet get = new HttpGet("http://xxxxx");//edit url removed.
        DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(get);
        String result = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(result);
        if(!obj.isNull("title")){
            testResult= obj.getString("title");
            Log.d("Test","Test1:"+ testResult);
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return testResult;//
}
```

and Then TextView.setText(testResult); 
It works for me.

it's Traditional Chinese String:"要聞--華爾街日報"
May be your ROM has no Traditional Chinese font？？？？

Comment: Doesnt work, this gives me a JSONException while parsing (at: new JsonObject(result))

Comment: If you use android SDK Json Parser, you should use new org.json.JSONObject(String)

Comment: Doesnt work either the title data looks like this after URLEncode: %E8%A6%81%E8%81%9E--%E8%8F%AF%E7%88%BE%E8%A1%97%E6%97%A5%E5%A0%B1

Comment: I included the url where you can access the json data

Comment: Has already edit my answer. and my mistake, it's nothing about URLDecoder.decode() or URLEncoder.encode() . it's Traditional Chinese String. May be your ROM has no Traditional Chinese font? I guess. Can you use Emulator to try this code?

Comment: hmm it works for you? looks extremely like my code ;-) Maybe my rom cant handle chinese !anymore! i got a nexus s with android 4.0.3 Stock rom. I parsed and displayed chinese xml with version 2.3 and erverything worked. Maybee that really changed... Thanks so far for your help, you got the accepted answer ;-)

Comment: one more, could you please mask the url in your answer? that would be nice :-)

Answer (score 0):

When you receive your JSON, you may have to decode the UTF-8 result when you're building your result. Have a look at utf8 decoding. Something similar to [this, but with JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4629456/utf8-encoding-in-android-when-invoking-rest-webservice)

Comment: im already using this UTF-8 Parameter: String json= EntityUtils.toString(responseEntity, HTTP.UTF_8); but without effect