# Error reading from html.class

Tags: android, http

I get this error while accessing a php script:

```
W/System.err: Error reading from ./org/apache/harmony/awt/www/content/text/html.class
```

The offending code snippet is as follows:

```
URL url = "http://server.com/path/to/script"
is = (InputStream) url.getContent();
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
String line = null;
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    sb.append(line + "\n");
}
is.close();
```

The error is thrown on the second line. A Google search on the error turned up 0 results. This warning doesn't affect the flow of my application and its more an annoyance rather than a problem. it also only occurs on a API 11 device (works fine on API 8 & 9 devices)

Comment: can you post your entire Logcat

Comment: @K_Anas This is my entire error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're querying a PHP script, I'm pretty sure declaring a URL and then trying to get an InputStream off it isn't the right way to do it...

Try something like:

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("http://someurl.com");

try {
// Execute HTTP Get Request
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpGet);

HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

if (entity != null) {

    InputStream instream = entity.getContent();
    String result = convertStreamToString(instream);

            // Do whatever with the data here


            // Close the stream when you're done
    instream.close();

    }
}
catch(Exception e) { }
```

And for easily converting the stream to a string, just call this method:

```
private static String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) {

    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    String line = null;
    try {
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            is.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not to use `HttpClient`? IMHO, it is a better way to make http calls. Check how it can be used [here](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidNetworking/article.html#http_apachehttp). Also make sure to not reinvent the wheel with reading the response from InputStream, instead use [EntityUtils](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4631237/247013) for that.

Comment: Basically I second what Cruceo suggests, however there is a better way of reading the response - using the `EntityUtils`.

Comment: That's genius. I didn't even know that existed. Thanks!