# HttpURLConnection header max length in Android

Tags: java, android, httprequest

I have the following code

## Update:There problem exists only in Android apps,it works fine in a java application

*Java (Not working for large header value)*

```
URL url = new URL("MyUrl"); //<===This could even be http://www.google.com  
HttpURLConnection request = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

String userCredentials = "username:AAAAABBBBBBBBCCCCSSSSSSSSSDDDDDDDDDDBE4B97CC9E81DB";
String basicAuth = "Basic " +  android.util.Base64.encodeToString(
            userCredentials.getBytes(), android.util.Base64.DEFAULT);
request.setRequestProperty ("Authorization", basicAuth);

request.connect();
InputStream stream = (InputStream) request.getContent();
```

I get a ClassNotFoundException when I call getContent()

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "org.apache.harmony.awt.www.content.text.html__charset_us_ascii" on path: DexPathList[[directory "."],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
```

in ClassLoader.class Line 514

```
 protected Class<?> loadClass(String className, boolean resolve) throws ClassNotFoundException {
    Class<?> clazz = findLoadedClass(className);


    if (clazz == null) {
        ClassNotFoundException suppressed = null;
        try {
            clazz = parent.loadClass(className, false);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            suppressed = e;
        }

        if (clazz == null) {
            try {
                clazz = findClass(className);
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                e.addSuppressed(suppressed);
               //className=org.apache.harmony.awt.www.content.text.html__charset_us_ascii
                throw e;  //<===The code crashes here

            }
        }
    }

    return clazz;
}
```

The problem is the size of the Authorization header,even if it is not that big (88 characters)
If I change the value of the header to something smaller it works.
**Can I change somehow the max size of the header?**

I have tried it from other platforms (Windows ,Windows Phone ,Web  ) and it works fine,the problem is not on my server.

**jQuery (Works always)**

```
var usernameAndPasword=["username","AAAAABBBBBBBBCCCCSSSSSSSSSDDDDDDDDDDBE4B97CC9E81DB"].join(":");
var authorizationHeaderValue="Basic "+   window.btoa(usernameAndPasword);

$.ajax({
    url : "http://...",
    type: "GET",
    beforeSend: function (request) {    request.setRequestHeader("Authorization", authorizationHeaderValue); },
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)  {   alert(data +  "\n" + textStatus ); },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){ alert(jqXHR.responseText +  " \n " + textStatus + " \n"+errorThrown); }
  });
```

**C# (Works always)**

```
 HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(requestUristring);
 request.Method = "GET";
 request.Headers["Accept-Encoding"] = "gzip, deflate";

 var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("username" + ":" + "AAAAABBBBBBBBCCCCSSSSSSSSSDDDDDDDDDDBE4B97CC9E81DB" );
 var base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
 request.Headers["Authorization"] = "Basic " + base64;

 HttpWebResponse webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponseAsync().Result;
```

Comment: How do you know that's the problem? And where's the stack trace?

Comment: What kind of other platforms it is running?

Comment: looks like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11216078/error-reading-from-html-class

Comment: @chokdee Windows,WindowsPhone,Web.I updated my question with code samples

Answer (score -3):

as you are using base64 encoding the maximum length for the encoded string should be 64, and if MIME then the maximum length for the encoded string should be 76.

For more information please check [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64)

Comment: Thanks for the reply!The string can be >64,Look the  quote from Thomas Hobbes' Leviathan from your link