# Changing UTF encoding in android

Tags: android, utf-8, textview

I'm sending data between my Android device and server and for some reason, all of my é gets displayed as Ã©. But it gets properly displayed on my browser (same data). Through some searching, I discovered that the UTF encoding may be different from my browser and my device.

How can I display TextViews with a certain UTF encoding? (UTF-8). Or is there an app-wide setting that I can set? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, found a duplicate and solution here:
[UTF8 Encoding in Android when invoking REST webservice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4629456/utf8-encoding-in-android-when-invoking-rest-webservice)

```
HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
... // probably some other code to check for HTTP response status code
HttpEntity responseEntity = response.getEntity();
String xml = EntityUtils.toString(responseEntity, HTTP.UTF_8);
```